# Reputation graph not showing up to current date?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

looks like the reputation graph on stackoverflow only shows finished full weeks and not up to current date. confirm? is it a feature or a bug?

--
Basically I just realized  that the date window in the graph and the input fields below don't always match exactly.
Today's (2011/01/20) screenshot is quite fine. The graph is up to  2011/01/19 where as the input field implies 20111/01/20.

[image: repgraph_enddate]

Yesterday when I opened the question my graph was up to 2011/01/15 and the input field for end date 2011/01/19.

The end date input field value defaults always to "today" but the end date shown in the graph is behind. Over the last 2 weeks I've recognized such small differences from one day / several days / up to near one week.

Comment: No, it should be like that, could you please provide a screenshot!

Comment: @Trufa: sorry can't add screenshot with the so-meta account having a reputation below 10

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm on IE7 right now, and the "selection" part of the graph overhangs the right edge (as per your image), but otherwise is functionally correct.

Comment: I don't mean browser or graph overhang issues. If I click and drag to the right in the graph it will copy the most recent end date to the input field below. This is often less than the current today's date. Still it's possible to manually enter more recent / today's date but the graph content will not update to show this cap of most recent data up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce this today. It's probably fixed?